# angular-cli compilation error + monorepo: error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I have a monorepo set up with two packages. One is the main application, let's call it `app`, and the other is a shared library that the main application uses, let's call it `lib`. Both are TypeScript/Angular projects.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
monorepo/
  packages/
    app/
    lib/
```

I am trying to configure the `app` project so that when it sees an import from the `lib` package, instead of going to `node_modules` I want it to go to the output directory from building the `lib` package. So I have in my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "lib/*": ["../lib/dist/*"]
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run `ng build` in the `app` folder, I get the following error messages (the same error twice, from two different locations):

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
../lib/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/ng_dev_mode.d.ts(9,11): error TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ngDevMode'.
```

It's like it's trying to load Angular twice, one from the `app` directory and one from the `lib` directory.

Comment: find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest, It's indeed trying to load angular twice.
There are 2 solutions for this :

**Solution 1**: force the use of the angular version defined in the app.  In the app, in tsconfig.json, in 'path' property, add the line below. It forces to use the angular lib that is located in the node_modules of your app (adapt the relative path according to your project)

```
"paths": {
  ...
  "@angular: ["../node_modules/@angular"],
  ...
```

**Solution 2**: create a symlink to your library into your app.

1. Build your lib, your lib is now built inside `my-lib-folder\dist\my-lib`
2. Go to your app folder
3. execute `npm install ..\my-lib-folder\dist\my-lib`.  This will create a symlink in your app's node_modules that point to your lib dist.
4. edit tsconfig.json and add a path to the dist of your lib

```
"paths": {
  ...
  "my-lib": ["dist.my-lib"]
  ...
```

**In both cases, check your imports :**

```
OK  : import {MyLibModule} from 'my-lib/';
NOK : import {MyLibModule} from '../my-lib-folder/my-lib/...';
```

In the later case, the angular version will still be loaded relatively from the import location.